# error: file 'nixpkgs' was not found in the Nix search path (add it using $NIX_PATH or -I)

Tags: ubuntu, installation, nix, nixos, nixpkgs

I've used `sh <(curl -L https://nixos.org/nix/install) --daemon` to install Nix.
After installation completed run `nix-shell -p nix-info --run "nix-info -m"` to verify the installation.
It returns the following error

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAhGa.png)

```
warning: Nix search path entry '/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/kana/channels' does not exist, ignoring
error: file 'nixpkgs' was not found in the Nix search path (add it using $NIX_PATH or -I)

       at «string»:1:25:

            1| {...}@args: with import <nixpkgs> args; (pkgs.runCommandCC or pkgs.runCommand) "shell" { buildInputs = [ (nix-info) ]; } ""
             |                         ^
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)
```

Comment: Are you on Ubuntu 22.04? I'm having the very same problem, and it's in a new terminal. Verified that e.g. `$NIX_PATH` is set too.

Comment: Hi, I'm encountering the same problem. Did you manage to solve it ?

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue. Every reference of `<nixkpgs>` in my scripts failed with the error message you described, on a freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.

My solution:

```bash
nix-channel --add https://nixos.org/channels/nixpkgs-unstable
nix-channel --update
```

For a specific [stable version](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Nix_channels#The_official_channels) of nixpkgs you can run something like this:

```bash
nix-channel --add https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-23.11 nixpkgs
nix-channel --update
```

To verify, that your issue is actually mine, the output of `nix-channel --list` was empty for me.

I guess there is a bug in the installation. I used the multi-user install process as you did.

Comment: Same here, on macOS 13, ARM M1 Pro

Comment: Why unstable? That's weird. But it worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer If you're not running NixOS, unstable is the only channel

Comment: This worked for me on a MacBook but I needed to open a new shell after updating the channel the first time.

Answer (score 2):

make sure that the nix environment file is sourced correctly. Try to start a **new terminal** as described in https://nix.dev/tutorials/install-nix#verify-installation

Comment: "nix environment file is sourced correctly" am I having a stroke? Does the install guide mention an environment file anywhere? I'm following the guide exactly, except I'm using the "nix" package in Arch Linux rather than their install script. The [Arch Nix wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Nix) also doesn't mention any environment file.

Comment: The Arch Nix wiki defines in step 2:
Configure environment: `$ nix-env --install`

Comment: Not sure what that does, but in my defense that was added to the wiki several weeks after my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimate what worked for me was to take matters into my own hands and set the NIX_PATH variable manually, like so:

```bash
export NIX_PATH=nixpkgs=https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/74e2faf5965a12e8fa5cff799b1b19c6cd26b0e3.tar.gz
```

(I eventually added it to my `~/.bashrc` and `~./zshrc files`). I use a MacBook btw.